# Proof of the Axiom of Choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, axiom-of-choice

This exercise is from Bloch's book and can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=QJ_537n8zKYC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=Suppose%20that%20every%20surjective%20function%20has%20a%20right%20inverse.%20Prove%20the%20axiom%20of%20choice.%20By%20Exercise%203.5.2,%20it%20is%20sufficient%20to%20prove%20the%20Axiom%20of%20Choice%20for%20Pairwise%20Disjoint%20Sets&source=bl&ots=6yZmfkd_uC&sig=s_J3UR1zEewlxm_0RiiTXzeH-7k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ8NT4i8jKAhVDKyYKHWrwAp0Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=Suppose%20that%20every%20surjective%20function%20has%20a%20right%20inverse.%20Prove%20the%20axiom%20of%20choice.%20By%20Exercise%203.5.2%2C%20it%20is%20sufficient%20to%20prove%20the%20Axiom%20of%20Choice%20for%20Pairwise%20Disjoint%20Sets&f=false). Bloch introduces equivalent variations of the axiom of choice where the one that will be proven is stated in terms of functions:

> **AC1** Let $I$ be a nonempty set, and let $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of nonempty sets indexed by I. Then there is a function $f: I \rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ such that $f(i) \in A_i$ for all $i \in I$.

As you can read from the text from the above link, the author suggests that **AC1** can be deduced from **AC2** below

> **AC2** Let $I$ be a nonempty set, and let  $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of nonempty, pairwise disjoint sets indexed by I. Then there is a function $f: I \rightarrow \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ such that $f(i) \in A_i$ for all $i \in I$.

Since the second definition implies the first, it is sufficient to prove the second version of AC, which will imply the first version.

We will prove that if every surjective function has a right inverse, then **AC2** is true, from which it follows that **AC1** is true.

Here is my attempt of a proof.

Suppose that every surjective function has a right inverse, and let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be such a surjective function with a right inverse $g: B \rightarrow A$ where $A$ and $B$ are nonempty sets. Since $f$ is surjective and $g$ is a right inverse of $f$ it follows that $g$ is injective (this fact can be proven by contradiction). Since $g$ is a function every $b \in B$ is defined, so that the image $g(\{b\}) \neq \varnothing$. Further, the injectivity of $g$ implies that $g(\{b_1\}) \cap g(\{b_2\}) = \varnothing$ for arbitrary $b_1, b_2 \in B$ such that $b_1 \neq b_2$. Observe also that $g(\{b\})$ contains only one element for each $b$. Finally,  it is clear that $A = \bigcup_{b \in B} g(\{b\})$ since $g$ is injective,$f$ is defined on $A$, and $g$ is defined on $B$. If we now consider the family $\{g(\{b\})\}_{b \in B}$, it is clear that this collection contains nonempty, pairwise dsjoint sets. Because $A = \bigcup_{b \in B} g(\{b\})$, we have $g:B \rightarrow \bigcup_{b \in B} g(\{b\})$, which is the desired choice function in the second definition above. Therefore, the AC of the first defintiion follows.

$\blacksquare$

Any criticisms or advice on the above proof is most welcome. I am unsure about my reason for the set equality $A = \bigcup_{b \in B} g(\{b\})$, but it can be proven formally in the traditional manner in demonstrating that the two sets are subsets of each other, but I wanted to keep my reasons for their equality concise, so I extracted the main arguments from such a proof and put them in this proof for the AC.

Thanks!

Comment: What *are* you trying to prove actually? If we call the first indented  thing AC1 and the second AC2, do yo want to show AC2 $\iff$ AC1?

Comment: AC2 \rightarrow AC!

Comment: "Since the second definition implies the first, it is sufficient to prove the second version of AC, which will imply the first version." It sounds like you're proving the 2nd version from some third thing — what is that? Is it "every surjection has a right inverse?" That's another equivalent form of AC.

Comment: The theorem is, "If every surjective function has a right inverse, then AC2 is true." From the theorem, it follows that AC1 is true. The problem is clearly stated in the link I provided; nonetheless, I edited my post.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the link, it doesn't exactly scream. General critique: You use names for things without defining them. What are $A$ and $B$? Nowhere do you say. In general it's verbose & you repeat yourself.

Comment: You should probably start with "We will (be attempting to) prove that if every surjective function has a right inverse, then we can conclude the Axiom of Choice in two different forms."Always helps your readers to start with the question at hand, and then give specifics.

Comment: @BrianO I defined $A$ and $B$ in the first sentence of the proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good point! I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @BenedictVoltaire That sounds weird. "If every surjective function has a right inverse, then AC2 is true" is true even if we assume that AC1 is false, so it does not follow from that theorem

Comment: Since you're attempting to prove AC2, I would expect that you'd start with some indexed family for which you will prove that a choice function exists. Define  $A = \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$, and just use $I$ instead of $B$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm just trying to do an exercise. The AC2 is the formulation of the axiom of choice that the author wants to be proven. In another exercise, it was shown that AC2 is equivalent to AC1, so if AC2 can be proven, then AC1 follows.

Comment: Anyway, assume all surjective functions have a right inverse. Let $I$ be a set and $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a familiy of nonempty disjoint sets. We want to show that there exists $f\colon I\to \bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ with $f(i)\in A_i$. We have a function $g\colon\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\to I$, $a\mapsto\bigcup\{\,i\in I\mid a\in A_i\,\}$ and a right inverse of that is what we are looking for

Comment: You might want to state what the exercise you are trying to solve is (other than directing us to a page with several exercises); and a better title would also be helpful.

Comment: You're not totally clear what you're asking and I don't want to bother reading the link because I might not understand what that page of the book is saying anyway and might still not know for sure what you're trying to ask. Did you assume it could be proven every surjective function has a right inverse? Because that statement is not provable, some readers might not be able to figure out that you assumed it and know what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof does not prove $\sf AC2$ as stated. It does show that if $f\colon A\to B$ is a surjection, and $g$ is a right inverse, then $g$ is a choice function from *a* family of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets.

What you need to do is start with *a* family of pairwise disjoint non-empty sets, and then use that family of produce a surjection whose right inverse will give you (directly or indirectly) a choice function.

Comment: I attempted a proof but am getting nowhere with it, and it's probably due to me not understanding how a choice function will arise given a family of pairwise disjoint nonempty sets, a surjective function and a right inverse. If you wouldn't mind providing a proof in your answer, that would be great.

Comment: If $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a pairwise disjoint family, what can you say about $A=\bigcup A_i$ and $B=I$. What is the obvious surjection?

Comment: It would be $f$ itself?

Comment: Yes, but you need to find some surjection first. What would it be given these $A$ and $B$? How do you map $a\in A$ to an element of $B$?

Comment: I guess it is not obvious to me. One of the commentors mentioned a function from the union of these sets to the indexing set, but I don't see how that is a choice function

Comment: You're not looking for a choice function. You're looking for a surjection.

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe if we had a mapping $h(a_i)=i$, for some $i \in I$, but it seems to not be surjective, I think.

Comment: You are given $a\in A$, which is the disjoint union of the $A_i$'s. What is the reason that $a\in A$?

Comment: If $a \in A$ is given, then $a$ being an element of $A$ is true by assumption, right? We also know that $A$ is nonempty, so the dis joint union is also nonempty. Otherwise, I guess $a \in A$ because $g(b)=a$ for each $b \in B$.

Comment: You're stressing out and mixing all sort of things here. Forget all that. Calm down, clear your mind, and start over. If $a\in A$, what could have possibly made it an element of the disjoint union?

Comment: If $a \in A$, then there exists an $i \in I$ such that $a \in A_i$. But because $A$ is the union of disjoint subsets, each $a$ belongs to a unique $A_i$. So $a \in A_i$ because an $i$ exists.

Comment: Correct. So if every $a\in A$ there exists a unique $i$ such that $a\in A_i$, what sort of surjection can you think of that maps $A$ onto $I$?

Comment: We can define a function $f:\bigcup A_i \rightarrow I$ by $f(a_i)=i$. It seems to be surjective because we can consider the function $g:I \rightarrow \bigcup A_i$ defined by $g(i)=a_i$. Then $g$ would be a right inverse of $f$, implying that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: You are correct that $f$ is surjective. You're not correct about the reasoning. To deduce that there is a right inverse, you need the axiom of choice, or the assumption that $f$ was surjective to begin with (because we already assume that surjective functions have inverses). But from the fact that for each $i\in I$, $A_i$ is not empty you get the *definition* of a surjective function. ***Now*** use your assumption about the existence a right inverse, what can you say about a right inverse of $f$? What is $g(i)$?